# Check if timestamp is x hours old?

Tags: php, strtotime

Simple question, but I couldn't find any related topics that match this exact scenario. Everything I found involved MySQL or date and time rather than just time.

I have a timestamp stored in a variable in the format of:

1325960262

Produced by:

```
$newTimeStamp = time();
```

**How can I check if this timestamp is older than 2 hours?**

I tried:

```
if (strtotime($ratesTimeStamp) <= strtotime('-2 hours')) {
    echo "OLDER";
} else {
    echo "not older";
}
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Drop the first `strtotime`; the variable is already in timestamp form:

```
if ($ratesTimeStamp <= strtotime('-2 hours')) {
    echo "OLDER";
} else {
    echo "not older";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```php
$testedTime = 1325960262;
$currentTime = time();

if($currentTime - $testedTime > 7200){
    /// Older than 2 hours
}
```