# Check whether timestamp to present has been 3 hours - php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if timestamp is x hours old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771981/check-if-timestamp-is-x-hours-old)

How do I determine whether it has been 3 hours or more from a `timestamp` (formatted like `2012-08-06 18:22:02`) to the current time, in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (time() > (strtotime($timeToCheck) + 10800))
```

Comment: Could you please also share some code that will format the timestamp to "human regular" formats, for the benefit of this asker? :)

Comment: @L0j1k, you mean you don't understand `2012-08-06 18:22:02` ?